# Asp net mvc type URL in a .aspx file

Tags: asp.net

Is it at all possible to use asp net mvc type urls (ex: `www.foo.com/bar` or `www.foo.com/bar/foobar`) with an (or multiple) .aspx file(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [use the routing module](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/25/routing-for-web-forms-in-asp.net-4.0.aspx) in classic webforms application.

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for. I will check then mark as answer accordingly.

Comment: sorry it took long...This is what I was looking for.